# css transition with form in div

Tags: html, css, forms, transition

I am trying to get a box which is faded out, if I clicked on it. It is working but the form doesn't.

If I click on '17 | Lampe im Esszimmer ... C301 | Frau Müller' then 'Beschreibung' and 'Notiz' appeared, but I miss the complete form.

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
                p {width: 320px; margin: 0px;}
                form {width: 320px; margin: auto;}
                #main {background-color: brown;}
                #id17 {background-color: blue; height: 0; overflow: hidden; transition: height 500ms ease-in 0s;}
                #id17:target {height: 100px;}
                .center {text-align: center;}

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='main' class='center'>
            <a href=#id17>17 | Lampe im Esszimmer ...<br>C301 | Frau Müller</a><br>
            <div id='id17' class='center'><br>
                Beschreibung:<br>
                Lampe im Esszimmer defekt. Es ist eine LED Birne.<br>
                Notiz:<br>
                Hier steht eine Notiz, wenn eine geschrieben wurde<br>
                <form id='id17' action='test.php' method='post'>
                    <fieldset>
                        <select name='std'>
                            <option value='0'>0</option>
                            <option value='15'>15</option>
                            <option value='30'>30</option>
                            <option value='45'>45</option>
                        </select><br>
                        <select name='min'>";
                            <option value='15'>15</option>
                            <option value='30'>30</option>
                            <option value='45'>45</option>
                            <option value='60'>60</option>
                        </select><br>
                        <input type='submit' value='erledigt'>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not alone with that question. I read it already, but it still unanswered.

Did I make my Point clear?

Comment: You used the id `id17` twice. For the container div, and for the form. IDs should be unique. Use classes instead: `<form class="bla" ...` and address it in your css with `.bla{ ... }`

Comment: Due to this css style overflow: hidden; form is not displaying in page.

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem: dont use id in `form` tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
                p {width: 320px; margin: 0px;}
                form {width: 320px; margin: auto;}
                #main {background-color: yellow;}
                #id17 {background-color: green; height: 0; overflow: hidden; transition: height 500ms ease-in 0s;}
                #id17:target {height: 400px;}
                .center {text-align: center;}

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='main' class='center'>
            <a href=#id17>17 | Lampe im Esszimmer ...<br>C301 | Frau Müller</a><br>
            <div id='id17' class='center'><br>
                Beschreibung:<br>
                Lampe im Esszimmer defekt. Es ist eine LED Birne.<br>
                Notiz:<br>
                Hier steht eine Notiz, wenn eine geschrieben wurde<br>
                <form id='' action='test.php' method='post'>
                    <fieldset>
                        <select name='std'>
                            <option value='0'>0</option>
                            <option value='15'>15</option>
                            <option value='30'>30</option>
                            <option value='45'>45</option>
                        </select><br>
                        <select name='min'>";
                            <option value='15'>15</option>
                            <option value='30'>30</option>
                            <option value='45'>45</option>
                            <option value='60'>60</option>
                        </select><br>
                        <input type='submit' value='erledigt'>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help!!!!

But I found a mistake made on my own.

I limited the #id17:target-height to 400px. I think that was the problem. With my new CSS lines, it works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Designtest</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <style>
            p {width: 320px; margin: 0px;}
            form {width: 320px; margin: auto;}
            #main {background-color: brown;}
            #id17 {background-color: blue; height: 0; overflow: hidden; transition: height 500ms ease-in 0s;}
            #id17:target {height: 100%;}
            #id18 {background-color: blue; height: 0; overflow: hidden; transition: height 500ms ease-in 0s;}
            #id18:target {height: 100%;}
            .center {text-align: center;}
            .id17 {overflow: visible; height: 100px;}
            .id18 {overflow: visible; height: 100px;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id='main' class='center'>
            <a href=#id17>17 | Lampe im Esszimmer ...<br>C301 | Frau Müller</a><br>
            <div id='id17' class='center'><br>
                Beschreibung:<br>
                Lampe im Esszimmer defekt. Es ist eine LED Birne.<br>
                Notiz:<br>
                Hier steht eine Notiz, wenn eine geschrieben wurde<br>
                <form class='id17' action='test.php' method='post'>
                    <fieldset>
                        <select name='std'>
                            <option value='0'>0</option>
                            <option value='15'>15</option>
                            <option value='30'>30</option>
                            <option value='45'>45</option>
                        </select><br>
                        <select name='min'>";
                            <option value='15'>15</option>
                            <option value='30'>30</option>
                            <option value='45'>45</option>
                            <option value='60'>60</option>
                        </select><br>
                        <input type='submit' value='erledigt'>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
            <a href=#id18>17 | Lampe im Esszimmer ...<br>C301 | Frau Müller</a><br>
            <div id='id18' class='center'><br>
                Beschreibung:<br>
                Lampe im Esszimmer defekt. Es ist eine LED Birne.<br>
                Notiz:<br>
                Hier steht eine Notiz, wenn eine geschrieben wurde<br>
                <form class='id18' action='test.php' method='post'>
                    <fieldset>
                        <select name='std'>
                            <option value='0'>0</option>
                            <option value='15'>15</option>
                            <option value='30'>30</option>
                            <option value='45'>45</option>
                        </select><br>
                        <select name='min'>";
                            <option value='15'>15</option>
                            <option value='30'>30</option>
                            <option value='45'>45</option>
                            <option value='60'>60</option>
                        </select><br>
                        <input type='submit' value='erledigt'>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```